# readtimeout while reading data from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeout

I am getting following error for some of the tables having large amount of data.

ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}

my query is,

select count(1) from rawdata_testing;
select count(1) from rawdata_testing where kpi='test' and channel_name='testchannel' allow filtering;

Here my partition keys are kpi and channel_name. and clustering keys are store_name ASC, visit_date ASC, id ASC.

In data, I am having 6 different kpi and 2 different channel_name.

I have 4 cassandra nodes and all of them configured like below,

read_request_timeout_in_ms: 3600000

write_request_timeout_in_ms: 3600000

request_timeout_in_ms: 300000

which more property needs to set?

Comment: Both count(1) and allow filtering are expensive operation. I that's why you are getting timeout exception. Show your table structure and estimate number of data

Comment: The issue is solved. we increase the 'range_request_timeout_in_ms'. Now I am able to get the result.

Comment: Data can be retrieve faster if you use counter. then you don't have to increase the request timeout

Comment: what do you mean by counter?

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html